# Access img tags or src which is inside multiple divs with same class name

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a `swiper` slider where I need to add images to individual div with the same class name. I want to access or take all those images or src and push into an array. I know it can be accessed using `classname` but, it gets you only one `img` using `classname`, I want to access all the `divs` and get all the `img` tags or src. Is there a way to do that?

```
      <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="/1.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="1305" height="548" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="2.png" border="0" alt="" width="1097" height="361" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="3.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="1305" height="548" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="4.jpg" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="5.jpg" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
      </div>
```

Comment: *I know it can be accessesed using classname but, it gets you only one img using classname* which code did you try that provided you such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can access all image by class name. But also you can use `querySelectorAll` to

```js
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide > img");
//console.log(nodeList)

//only get sources:

var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);

console.log(array.map(t=>t.getAttribute('src')))
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="/1.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="1305" height="548" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="2.png" border="0" alt="" width="1097" height="361" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="3.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="1305" height="548" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="4.jpg" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="5.jpg" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` for this.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide > img')).map(ele => ele.src)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you what you probably want:

```
let arrImages = [];
document.querySelectorAll('div.swiper-slide img').forEach((img) => {
  arrImages.push(img.src);
});


console.log(arrImages);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the `src`'s, use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=nl) like so:

```js
const all = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide img'));
const lnk = all.map(t => t.getAttribute('src'));

console.log(lnk);
```

```html
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="/1.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="1305" height="548" />
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="2.png" border="0" alt="" width="1097" height="361" />
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="3.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="1305" height="548" />
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="4.jpg" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="5.jpg" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" />
</div>
```

```json
[
  "/1.jpg",
  "2.png",
  "3.jpg",
  "4.jpg",
  "5.jpg"
]
```